# How to turn back on SSLV3 protocol for my gmail ids?

Tags: email, gmail, lotus-notes

My problem is a bit the reverse and concerns a recent problem downloading Email's to my pc.

There is no problem with sending using SMTP but I now see problems with receiving using via either Pop or IMAP servers.  Both report "Bad Peer Certificate Errors".

I believe I have resolved the cause of my problem receiving emails which is Gmail recently has by default disabled the SSLV3 protocol on its servers.

I must use Windows XP Professional and access my email with Lotus Notes Client R5.0.12.

My email client will work with one of the following sets of Internet Protocol:
V2.0
V3.0 Handshake
V3.0 Only
V3.0 w V2.0 Handshake
(Negotiate - one of the above)

Up until 07/28/2015 I successfully was able to receive emails using SSL Protocol V3.0 w V2.0 Handshake.

Apparently Gmail has "turned off"  this protocol shortly after 07/28/2015.

I need SSLV3 protocol TURNED BACK ON for MY gmail ids! Google/Gmail is of no help, they merely point you to their support forums where you could wander about for days!

So how can I do this? (rncox01@gmail.com)

Comment: If Google has stop accepting SSL connections then there isn't anything you can do except adapt to what Google will accept.  SSL3 is massively broken and should not be used.

Comment: Use mozilla Thunderbird on XP problem solved.  Either that, or for gmail just access it from inside your web browser.  Why do you have to use XP and Lotus Notes, obsolete version?  (Better make this a good story).  FYI: SSL is dead and it will soon be stripped from every software version.

Comment: @Ramhound it helps because Thunderbird supports TLS,  SSL is a lost cause.

Comment: @cybernard  - Indeed.  I didn't even think you were going down that route.

Comment: and because it is free so cost isn't an issue.

Comment: From a Gmail Forum: "Google's servers support SSLv3 encryption and they support the TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV flag... So they will negotiate SSLv3, if the client requests it, unless the fallback flag is set."

Comment: From a Gmail Forum: "Google's servers support SSLv3 encryption and they support the TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV flag... So they will negotiate SSLv3, if the client requests it, unless the fallback flag is set."  "Upgrade" is not an answer for me right now and retired at 62 I like my legacy system.  Eventually I will open a PMR with IBM to upgrade the Notes replicator, but what I need to know is where that flag is so as to turn it "off" for my Gmail Id, or the contact for someone to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that you need to upgrade.

Lotus Notes 5.0 was released in 1999. That's 16 years ago. There have been six major releases of Lotus Notes since then, with numerous maintenance releases and fix packs issued. All support for Notes 5.x [ended in September 2005](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?synkey=K757559R44578E06-B757743H80486B18-G083049A80160L05), which is just a month short of being a decade ago! And then there's Windows XP, which went out of support a little more than a year ago...

You simply should not be using this configuration. You cannot expect to make it work with properly secured web sites.

Answer (score 2):

SSLv3 has significant security flaws and is no longer considered secure, so many companies are pushing to move away from it.  See [RFC 7568](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568) for more information.

If Google has configured its servers to stop accepting SSL connections, it's unlikely you'll be able to convince the company to re-enable the protocol just for you.  It'd be better to talk with whoever's requiring you to use this deprecated, insecure protocol (on a deprecated, insecure operating system, no less) and see if you can upgrade to software that supports modern security protocols.